# Are all methods of solving YDSE problems equivalent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, double-slit-experiment

> In YDSE, $D=1m$, $d=1mm $ and $\lambda=0.5mm$. Find the distance between the central maximum and the first maximum.

### My attempt:

The distance between the central maximum and the first maximum is the definition of fringe width, hence:
$$\beta=\frac{\lambda D}{d}=0.5$$

### Given solution:

Let the angular position of first maximum be $\theta\implies \sin(\theta)=\frac{\lambda}{d}=\frac 12\implies \theta = 30^\circ$

Therefore

$$\beta=D\tan \theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$

---

I tried equating both the answers and arrived at the fact that $\sin \theta = \tan \theta$ which seems to be a contradiction..?  Seems like the two solutions aren't actually compatible with each other. However, I think that the answer should be the same because in YDSE we assume small angles.

Comment: What is YDSE? The most important part about getting different answers is to do calculations an odd number of times (or to try an odd number of approaches) - otherwise you can't decide which one is more likely to be true.

Comment: Your answers are close to each other. Suspiciously close. Almost as if one is an approximation of the other. An approximation which gets better as the angle gets smaller. If you don't catch my drift, try deriving the formulas you presented.

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} } \approx .577$$

Comment: That's an odd approach @Vadim :-)

Comment: I might be wrong on this but the source of error might be that $30 ^\circ $ is not a small enough angle. So your approximation of approximating sine as tangent of $30 ^\circ $ might not work very well. Just a guess!

Comment: @Buraian Teachers are not allowed to say this in class, but this is how it is often done when it comes to building medical equipment or airplanes. Pharma is a big exception - they know statistics ;)

Comment: So what I concluded is that this is just an extreme application(as evident from the wavelength of light given). The approximations that we used to obtain the result must not be used here.

Comment: I think your source of confusion is directly applying formulas. If you take into account the exact predictions of the model, I think you will find some approximation which you should not have taken. If I get time, I'll probably post an answer to this tomorrow, but I guess a lot of people here are much more qualified than me who can answer this better. Anyways, good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\sin \theta= \tan \theta$ which seems to be a contradiction..?

This isn't contradiction because in the proof (you can find it in any textbooks on optics) we have assume that $y <<s$ for which $$\sin\theta\approx \tan\theta\approx\theta$$

Now $\sin(30^0)=0.5$ and $\tan(30^0)=0.577$.
Which can be consider as good approximation. Note that the given answer is an exact answer with no approximation used but your is with approximation.